# select between ... range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named "color_indicator" like this:

```
ID   MIN    MAX  
1   2.00    NULL    
2   1.00    2.00    
3   NULL    1.00
```

and a query like this:

```
select * from color_indicator where VALUE ...
```

what I need to do is get the id of the table where VALUE is in the correct range.

Example if VALUE = 0.9 should return id 3.

How could I do it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the correct answer if `@Value=1`?

Comment: the ranges would be if: value <1, id = 3
if: value> = 1 and: value <= 2, id = 2
if: value> 2, id = 1

Comment: [edit] that into your question please.

Comment: That is quite unusual logic, and won't scale, normally one would always use `>= min, < max` rather than changing the operators around.

Comment: And is there ever a case when there might be more than 3 rows in your table? Because then your logic falls down also. How should it be handled in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think you want:

```
select ci.*
from color_indicator ci
where (:value >= min_value or min_value is null) and
      (:value <= max_value or max_value is null);
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for, excelent! Thanks man

Comment: @LuisAlbertoGonzalezDiaz a value of 1 will return you 2 rows here - is that what you want?

Comment: @DaleK oh, its true ... no, i want only 1 row

Comment: @LuisAlbertoGonzalezDiaz . . . You can choose an arbitrary matching row by adding `limit 1` to the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

Comment: Won't handle null and I think OP means value is a variable not a column.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a different approach, filter, order, top. This will only get one row. You would improve the performance of this approach by not leaving the first `[min]` value as `null`, instead setting it to (I assume) `0`:

```
declare @color_indicator table (id int, [min] money, [max] money);

declare @Value money = 1.1; -- 0.9 -- 2.1

insert into @color_indicator (id, [min], [max])
values
(1,   2.00,    NULL),    
(2,   1.00,    2.00),
(3,   NULL,    1.00);

select top 1 ci.*
from @color_indicator ci
where @value >= [min] or [min] is null
order by [min] desc;
```

Note: Query life is easier if you don't use reserved words such as min/max.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
-- The value you need to find
DECLARE @n FLOAT =5;

-- Query that gives you ID
SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Result WHERE @n BETWEEN ISNULL([MIN], 0) AND ISNULL([MAX], 0)
```